# ran the flutter doctor after android SDK installation and nothing happends

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have used instruction from official site. I have installed flutter than ran flutter doctor and saw standard massage about android SDK.
Than I have downloaded and installed Adroid SDK to custom folder from official site.
After that flutter doctor show nothing.

Comment: It simply prints nothing into the command-line?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add a picture to it, so we can see where it goes wrong. 
But if you run ```flutter doctor``` in CMD and it does not recocgnize the command, then it means you have not set up your enviroment variables correctly. Scroll down on [flutter installation tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) and find the part where it says *Update path*. All this is assumed that you are working on windows.